# Adding a custom field value to a drop down time value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been supporting a site development for mostly html and css work but have ended up with a couple extra javascript bits which i'm not overly confident on and looking at someone else's work is difficult enough!

Essentially, when a user checkouts and selects a delivery time this value needs to the base time (opening time spread out into slots) + the collection or delivery time.

Currently i've located this code which is what outputs the time, i'm not 100% on what i'm looking at but have a rough idea if pointed in the right direction.

```
<div class="step1 steps time">
      <select name="order_time" id="order_time_fields">
         <option value = " "> Choose selected time</option>
         <?php 
            foreach ($time_option as $key => $time) {
               echo '<option value = "'.$time.'">'.$time.'</option>';    
            }
         ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

This is a wordpress based site but very heavily edited.

The 2 custom fields are Delivery_time and collection_time

I'm not expecting a perfect answer but maybe something for me to look into

Thanks

**Slight Update -**

I've found a number of bits like this;

```
if($order_min == 1){

    $time_option[] = $hrs.':00 (ASAP)';

    $time_option[] = $hrs.':15';

    $time_option[] = $hrs.':30';

    $time_option[] = $hrs.':45';
}
```

How do I go about adding the custom fields to the array or the best way to output it for the `foreach` part?

Comment: It's just looping the $time_option as $value => $actual time you see, printing a drop down <select> with $time as the value and $time as what you see

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what would be my next step in a way to add in either delivery time or collection time custom field to finally output the correct time.

Or is this so far disconnected from what i'd need that this part might as well be re done?

Comment: Somewhere above, the array $time_option is set with different time values that should be displayed in the <SELECT>.  That foreach loop goes to each of them and prints the values as <option> of the <SELECT>.  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @Nic3500

Great, i've found the array with a number of different options in it for example

if($order_min == 1){

              $time_option[] = $hrs.':00 (ASAP)';

              $time_option[] = $hrs.':15';

              $time_option[] = $hrs.':30';

              $time_option[] = $hrs.':45';

is this the part that needs changing for the output?

Comment: Indeed, if you change the values included in the $time_option array, the display in the <SELECT> will change accordingly.  Good, you edited the question!  Yes change that.  Note, there might be another place where $time_option is set, but if this is the only place, go for it!

Comment: Just updated the main question with it so it's a bit more readable, didn't know it would do that!

so my final part to this... I have custom fields in wp which define the collect time and del time.

I guess what's the syntax or best way to add that time to this array?

Comment: Sorry if these are silly questions, it's a bit of a gap in my skills at the moment!